# The "add / show x more comments" showing itself after posting a comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

One screenshot will explain it the best:

[image: screenshot]

It shouldn't be there - appeared right after posting the comment. When reloading the page it disappears so something goes awry with the AJAX handling.

Clicking it is reloading the existing comment(s) and open the *new comment* text box.

Comment: I had just started writing a question reporting this exact bug.

Comment: Except, this was from March 2012, but now it's September 2013...???

Comment: @Jerry it's a different bug, [already reported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192691/152859) and a dev confirmed it but also said it's pointless to fix at this point. Anyhow, it's showing only after you **edit** a comment of yours, not adding, so different enough to deserve its own report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a race condition between posting a comment and displaying it now that realtime comments are enabled here on meta.  This bug will die on the next deploy.

Comment: Goodbye dear bug, and thanks for all the fish!

Comment: Jut in case you didn't notice, here is [related issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130169/live-notification-shown-for-own-edits)

Comment: FYI I am experiencing this bug, and this is well over a year after this was reported and fixed.