# "Add/show 1 other comment" bug strikes again

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments

So I've been experiencing this in the last few days: sometimes when someone replies to my comment, and I reply to the reply, then the "add/show 1 more comment" link appears immediately after I post my comment. However, when I click it, it disappears and nothing is shown.

I don't think it's that OP is posting two comments of which he deletes the second one, because this has happened to me several times, even when I was replying within 2-3 seconds.

I do, however, believe that this is more or less the same bug as [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126489/the-add-show-x-more-comments-showing-itself-after-posting-a-comment), except that I don't have to reload the page in order the link to be gone, and I also seem to be getting the erroneous behavior only if I reply to a comment which is itself a reply to an earlier comment of mine.

Unfortunately, I wasn't careful enough to take a screenshot last time this happened, but here's what I am talking about for those who like visual demonstration better:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, noticed it on and off so it's most likely some race condition.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd This has been already fixed once, but apparently came back :P

Comment: I considered upvoting this, but I didn't want to encourage the combination of the "Eeeeeek!", the freehand circle, and the unicorn.

Comment: Yep it's not surprising, with the recent changes to comments they probably swiped away some bug fixes.

Comment: @PeterOlson Those three have been included deliberately. I want to boost my Meta reputation.

Comment: @H2CO3 that's "Eeek" at most though. "Eeeeeek" is when something is really broken e.g. you see unicorns instead of question. :-D

Comment: I know they're deliberate. I just think you're trying too hard to boost your rep by using old jokes. ([We don't accept fun around here any more](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/)).

Comment: @Peter hey at least he's not oscillating! (new joke just for you ;))

Comment: @PeterOlson Also, there's the "don't use this, Meta is a serious place" tag, amirite?

Comment: Not fixed yet, flagged to reopen. (i.e. remove status-completed)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yeah, thanks!

Comment: Cheers, I also [recorded myself reproducing it](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nT69oXu-rL4).

Comment: @balpha we [got eeekified recently](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=eeeek%20is%3aquestion)! :(

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd All those young'uns not knowing [what an Eeeek post is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/83625/115866).

Comment: @balpha I know, but was too lazy/unsure to edit it myself.

Comment: See also [After adding a comment, SO says there are new comments to show but it is only yours](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195126/after-adding-a-comment-so-says-there-are-new-comments-to-show-but-it-is-only-y).  The issue is still occurring.

Comment: I've added a documented case with images to [After adding a comment, SO says there are new comments to show but it is only yours](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195126/after-adding-a-comment-so-says-there-are-new-comments-to-show-but-it-is-only-y); the problem is ongoing and does appear to have been forgotten about.  I'm sure it probably isn't the most critical bug in the system.  It is (mildly) annoying, though.

Answer (score 9):

<strike>I've got it.  I'll update when this is ready.</strike>

*Update*:  This is fixed.  Maybe.  For now.

*Update 2*: Localization is progressing, and the comments feature is on-deck, so I've been putting off spending any more time on comments until that's done. Putting this to [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) so I won't forget about it.

*Update 3*: refactored comments is basically done, and I fixed a couple of related bugs earlier today and haven't been able to reproduce this (not a cop-out...I did actually try).  If anyone notices this behavior again comment on this answer.

Comment: It seems to be back again...

Comment: No cigar. See [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nT69oXu-rL4), I was able to catch the bug and... reproduce it!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: localization is progressing, and the comments feature is on-deck, so I've been putting off spending any more time on comments until that's done.  I've put this to [meta-tag:status-deferred] so I won't forget about it.

Comment: Fair enough. :)

Comment: `Localization is progressing` me gusta!