# After adding a comment, SO says there are new comments to show, but it is only yours?

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, comments

For a few days now, when I add a comment, SO will (sometimes) show my comment and indicate that there are one or more new comments, and on showing the new comments, it is just my comment that is shown.  Just now, it told me there were 6 new comments; there weren't — there was just mine.

SO didn't used to get confused about that.  Please fix it so it is unconfused once more.

---

Specific context: [I have designed a sorting algorithm for a linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513817/i-have-designed-a-sorting-algorithm-for-a-char-linked-list-in-c-but-it-doesnt).

*I set out to reproduce it — the site recognized that it was under scrutiny and refused to cooperate.*

The problem seems to be intermittent, or to depend on the sequence of actions you undertake.  But I've noticed it on and off for most of this week.  I don't think it depends on having a lot of comments; I've seen it with a couple of comments in the question.  I'm not sure whether it is restricted to comments to the question; I think it can occur with comments to an answer too.

I've seen it with both Firefox (23.0.1) and Chrome (29.0.1547.57) on Mac OS X 10.8.4.

### Documentary Evidence

#### Question: [segfault during write to the realloc'd area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592115/segfault-during-write-to-the-reallocd-area)

When the question is first loaded there are a number of hidden comments (now 10, was 9 when I started):

[image: Showing 10 comments initially hiddent]

When I added a comment, it said there were 8 more to show:

[image: 8 more comments]

When I tried to show the '8 more comments', they weren't there:

[image: not 8 more comments]

After reloading and redisplaying, the comments available were:

[image: look at them all]

Strictly speaking, the images were generated in the order 2nd ('8 more'), 3rd ('not 8 more'), 1st ('10 more'), and 4th ('look at them all').  I've not tried adding yet another comment.  But this bug is still active a week or more after I reported it, and a month or more after it was first reported.

Comment: Yes, this is that same bug...maybe it has been going on longer than I realized.

Comment: It is still going on a month later, and it is still irritating.