# Old bug returning which shows "add / show X more comments" when it shouldn't

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, comments

I know [this was reported before and fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126489/the-add-show-x-more-comments-showing-itself-after-posting-a-comment), but it seems this bug has risen from the dead to haunt us once again.

Comment: Definite duplicate issue, but far different time period still. How long does this take to fix?

Comment: As [Ben says](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/192908/152859): "I've been putting off spending any more time on comments until that's done" where "that's" is refering to "Localization is progressing". So, 6-8 weeks. ;-)