# Status of Add/Show comment bug

Tags: bug, comments

I've noticed this strange behavior lately. Whenever I comment on a question or answer, the `add/show 1 more comment` link is displayed immediately, even when there aren't any new comments. When I click on the link, the message disappears, and no new comments are displayed. I have to reload the page to make sure there are no new comments on the thread.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

I'm unable to reproduce the issue with a strict procedure and it doesn't happen all the time. So I believe this to be some kind of race-condition. I've seen [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126555/220538) post on Meta and it's marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) but I'm still experiencing the issue.

I've also checked [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/192908/220538) answer and it says:

> Localization is progressing, and the comments feature is on-deck, so I've been putting off spending any more time on comments until that's done. Putting this to [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) so I won't forget about it.

So, I'm wondering, what's the status on this?

Comment: status-norepro.

Comment: This has been happening for me as well

Comment: @Undo: How about now? ^ :P

Comment: Well, status-norepro on this post, for me, right here, on this device.

Comment: I think it might depend on how many comments the post has. I've seen in on SO earlier today. No repro here.

Comment: It happens all the time to me.  I believe it occurs when you get the "add/show x more comments" appears while typing a comment, then you submit the comment.  The message will reappear every time there is a comment change until you reload the page

Comment: In my vague rememberings I think this is happening when a post already has enough comments to warrent a "show x more comments" which has been expanded

Comment: [status-reproduced-a-lot]

Comment: [It's not going to be fixed until localization is finished](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192691/add-show-1-other-comment-bug-strikes-again/192908#comment605167_192908). edit: Ah, just realized you linked to that. I believe that's the most current status...

Comment: @RichardTingle: I don't think there's any such limits.  I think I've seen this behavior on questions with < 4 comments.

Comment: The problem with vague rememberings

Comment: @psubsee2003: I don't think that's the case here. The issue can (sometimes) be re-produced on *very* old posts, too (which indirectly tells us that the issue isn't dependent on the *currently typing* status)

Comment: @RichardTingle: Haha, yes.

Comment: @Lance: Care to explain why this is closed as a duplicate when the issue hasn't been resolved yet?